# How to iterate over object in Angular 17 with new @for?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to refactor a small piece of HTML to migrate from *ngFor directive to the new @for

```
    <mat-menu #clientsMenu="matMenu">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of clientMenu | keyvalue">
        <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="sub_menu">{{ item.key }}</button>
        <mat-menu #sub_menu="matMenu" class="menu">
          <button *ngFor="let p of item.value" mat-menu-item (click)='changePlanta(p)'>
            <div>
              <span style="padding-right:10px;">{{p.nome_planta}}</span>
              <span>{{p.id_planta}}</span>
            </div>
          </button>
        </mat-menu>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-menu>
```

clientMenu is not an array, it's an object, so in this previous version keyvalue pipe is being used to iterate over keys (strings) and values (arrays of objects).

I tried to keep the same logic:

```
    <mat-menu #clientsMenu="matMenu">
      @for (client of clientMenu | keyvalue; track client){
        <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="sub_menu">{{ client.key }}</button>
        <mat-menu #sub_menu="matMenu" class="menu">
          @for (planta of client.value; track planta){
            <button mat-menu-item (click)='changePlanta(planta)'>
              <div>
                <span style="padding-right:10px;">{{planta.nome_planta}}</span>
                <span>{{planta.id_planta}}</span>
              </div>
            </button>
          }
        </mat-menu>
      }
    </mat-menu>
```

But I get `error TS2488: Type 'never' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`, in "client.value", which should be an array.

Class code is below:

```
 public clientMenu = {};

 async ngOnInit() {

    this.routeSubscription = this.routeGuards.authorized.subscribe(async (authorized) => {
      if (authorized){
        if (this.user.isUgm()){
          this.user.plantas = await this.http.centralGet('get_plantas');
    
          new Set(this.user.plantas.map(p=>p.nome_cliente)).forEach(c=>{
            this.clientMenu[`${c}`]= this.user.plantas.filter(p=>p.nome_cliente == c).sort((p1, p2) => p1.nome_planta.localeCompare(p2.nome_planta))
          })
          console.log('this.clientMenu', this.clientMenu)
        };
      };
    });
  };
```

`clientMenu` is logged as something like this (simplified):

```
{ client1: [{id_planta: 1, nome_planta: 'planta1'}, {id_planta: 2, nome_planta: 'planta2'}], client2: [...same logic...] }
```

How to use @for in this case?

Comment: The `KeyValuePipe` is expected to work here. Can you check the type of `clientMenu ` ?

Comment: `clientMenu` is defined as `public clientMenu = {};`
and then filled with `new Set(this.plantas.map(p => p.nome_cliente)).forEach(client => {
            this.clientMenu[${client}]= this.plantas.filter(p=>p.nome_cliente == client)
          })`
I checked that keys are strings and values are arrays of objects

Comment: @LudovicBeghin can you include the class code in the question too? And does the **same** TS code work well with the old `*ngFor` syntax?

Comment: @BennyHalperin I've updated the question. Yes, this code works with `*ngFor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `track client.key`

e.g.

```
@for(keypar of client|keyvalue;track keypar.key)
{
  <div>
  @for(item of keypar.value;let i=$index;track i)
  {
  <span>{{item}}</span>
  }
</div>
```

when

```
client={one:['one','one one'],two:['two','two 2','two 3']}
```

BTW use track with uniques property or the "item" (or the own $index) better than the own "item"

**Update** About strict mode

When we define some like

```
public clientMenu = {};
```

Angular in strict mode Angular understand that is of type "never"

We need give it some "type". We can do it with an interface, e.g.

```
interface CustomClient {
  value: {
    [key:string]: any
  }
}
//and use
client:CustomClient={}
```

Or directly

```
client:{[key:string]: any}={}
```

Comment: I still get the same `error TS2488: Type 'never' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator`. I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: @LudovicBeghin, sorry :(, you need declare your client some like `client:{[key:string]: any}={}` if only indicate `client={} //<-ERROR` makes "client" of type "never"